# Check Email Validation Django

Tags: django, validation, email

Can someone explain how to validate an email adress in Django?
So for Example i want to check if an email is a valid college email adress with the ending .edu . 
How can i do that?

```
from django import forms

from .models import SignUp

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ['full_name','email']

        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            return email
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your `SignUp.email` field is an `EmailField`, Django will take care of validating that it's a valid email address. All you need to do is check that it ends in `.edu`, and raise a `ValidationError` if it doesn't.

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ['full_name','email']

        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            if not email.endswith('.edu'):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Only .edu email addresses allowed")
            return email
```

If might be better to create a validator and add it to your model field. This way, Django will run your validator when you use your `SignUpForm` and when it does model validation in other places like the Django admin.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_edu_email_address(value):
    if email.endswith('.edu'):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Only .edu email addresses allowed")

class SignUp(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(validators=[validate_edu_email_address])
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a regular expression for your needs, or even better use some standard one.

```
import re

EMAIL_REGEX = r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)"

# EMAIL_REGEX = r'\w+@\.edu' # If you only want to allow edu.

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
...

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email and not re.match(EMAIL_REGEX, email):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid email format')

        return email
```

In fact, even better approach would be to use [`EmailField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield) as @Alasdair suggested, that would automatically ensures the same for you (unless you really need to limit the email addresses to your custom format).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify email in Django forms:

```
email_user_part_regex = re.compile(
    r"^(?=.{4,30}$)[\w\u0080-\uffff]+(?:[\.\-+][\w\u0080-\uffff]+)*$",
    re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE,
)

class ForgetPasswordEmailForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(label='email', max_length=200)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        validate_email.user_regex = email_user_part_regex
```